# How to make Google maps marker title blink in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uiviewanimation

I'm working with google maps api on iOS now and I'm stuck with this problem. I have a GMSMarker with a certain title.

```
markerTracker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
let markerImage = UIImage(named: "markerImage")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
markerTracker!.title = Constants.alert
/* Do some other GMSMarker setup here */
```

There's an easy way to make marker itself blink:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
                        self.markerTracker?.iconView!.alpha = 0.0
                    }, completion: nil)
```

The result will be flashing marker image and title windows staying still.

However, I want to do it vice versa, leave marker image immutable and make title window flashing.

Any ideas how to achieve this? It seems, that current API allows access only to a single view, which is iconView. I don't see a way to get a view for a title.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a source in which your custom image will blink over the map.

```
func animateFlash() {
        markerTracker.alpha = 0
        markerTracker.isHidden = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { markerTracker.alpha = 1.0 }) { finished in self.markerTracker.isHidden = true
            self.animateFlash()
        }
    }
```

Comment: No offence, but did you read my question properly? Your code does the same thing, as mine.